# 'realpath(): Permission denied' when running dotnet ef command as non-root in dotnet/sdk:3.1-bullseye container on k8s

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework, kubernetes, .net-core

## Problem

A container meant to run database migrations works locally, on Docker for Mac, but fails on Kubernetes, repeatedly logging

```
realpath(): Permission denied
Failed to resolve full path of the current executable [/proc/self/exe]
```

## Reproduction

I have an image built from the following Dockerfiles (other descendents of base not included)

```
#Dockerfile.base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-bullseye

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

ADD event_processor/dotnet /app
ADD classification_registry/topic_registry  /app/topic_registry

WORKDIR /app
```

and

```
#Dockerfile.migrate
FROM app-base

ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/app
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1000 app \
    && adduser --home /app --system --uid 2000 --ingroup app --shell /bin/sh appmigrate
RUN chown -R appmigrate /app
RUN chown -R appmigrate /root/.dotnet/tools
RUN chown -R appmigrate /tmp
USER appmigrate
ENV PATH="$PATH:/app/.dotnet/tools"
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

so if we let `unique-image-ref` be a unique tag for this built image, I am able to run the container locally, as I expect with

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user 2000 unique-image-ref dotnet-ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Configuring DB Access for migrations...
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.
```

So far so good. The problem arises in the Kubernetes cluster, when a Job is configured to run this container, with the following container definition

```
containers:
        - name: my-app-migration
          image: unique-image-ref
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          workingDir: /app
          command: ["dotnet-ef"]
          args:
            - database
            - update
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: app-conf
            - secretRef:
                name: app-secret
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
```

When I examine the logs from the container, I see nothing but the error (at the top of this post).

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, though I cannot articulate exactly *how* this change effects the fix.

```yaml
    containers:
        - name: my-app-migration
          image: unique-image-ref
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          workingDir: /app
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "dotnet-ef --project=Seismic.NotificationEventProcessor.RecoveryQueue database update"]
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: app-conf
            - secretRef:
                name: app-secret
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
```

So the fix is to [invoke the command from a new shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell), and pass the command to execute as a string (hence `-c`). But realistically, the details of this escape me.

I hope this helps someone else out with a very obscure error message. If anyone cares to expand on the underlying behavior, I would be glad to understand the relationships among docker, kubernetes, and bash in this regard.